# Spring Boot: RSA works, JKS doesn't

Tags: java, ssl

I want to enable SSL for my spring boot application.

I generated a keystore with this command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias myapp -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

`application.properties` contains:

```
server.port = 8443
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:tomcat.keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password = ###
server.ssl.key-password = !&*
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

First I had created JKS key store with this command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks -validity 3650
```

But I received error when visited `https://localhost:8443`:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

localhost uses an unsupported protocol.
```

Why it's working now and not then ?

I have a few other questions:
1.I looked at a few tutorials and they all suggested to put the keystore file in `src/main/resources`. Is this really a good idea?

2.What is the `key-store-password`? what is the `key-password`?

3.Is this all we have to do to enable SSL ? what about `crt` and `cer` files? where are they used ?

Comment: what about RSA keystore ? what do you mean that it is not for making ssl keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `localhost uses an unsupported protocol.` make sure the server is supporting a cipher which client can support.

`This site can’t provide a secure connection`, the message could be becasue the connection is not trusted! of course. here you would simply tell the client to ignore it.

You also set an alias in your JKS file, make sure you tell the server to load the correct alias.

placing the JKS in `src/main/resources` could be a good practice, but not essential, just make sure it's safe and accessible.

`crt` and `cer` are not required explicitly for java, but once you get a signed certificate by a CA, you would import the cert into the JKS to let the server finds the intermediate and root certs(if exists, root is not essential)

Once you generate a key by keytool, just keep the file safe. You need to generate the CSR value, also the same jKS is needed for trusted cert importing.

I also suggest to get some hand of OpenSSL(if possible) over JSSE.

Comment: Putting a resource it under `resources` folder means that it gets delivered to the user? if yes, why is it a good idea to deliver keystore to the client ?

Comment: C'mon! no dear, server won't send the private key of course! otherwise it's not called SSL. You even would ask for a certificate of the client to approve the connection. So client need to install a certificate then ask for the request (which is very rare) @ArianHosseinzadeh

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh one important thing is, you must be sure the resource folder you mentioned is not accessible publicly. Beside The server won't expose the key, but it might be accessible by FTP, HTTP, etc. so just keep it somewhere safe.

Comment: Well, `resources` folder is meant to be a place to put static files like `html`, `css`, `js` files.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh let say in java web profile, the WEB-INF folder is the place all classes, libs are located. but not accessible at all, and server won't map it to a shared static resource. Well just make sure it's safe, whatever it located.